# How to authenticate a RESTful JWT API from PHP

Tags: rest, laravel, cookies, jwt

I have a Laravel RESTful API that is controlled by JWT, and I want to authenticate it from another route. Here is the code:

```
//Route.php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
    Route::get('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');
});

Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index');

//Login.blade.php
<form action="http://domain.dev/api/authenticate" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

Now because I am using JWT, I get a token back which needs to be stored in a cookie. Then once the user is logged in they should be redirected to another view and the user will send this token as a header on every request.

I have googled a lot but could not find any tutorials that actually show how to make a proper request from PHP instead of a JS framework.

EDIT: I am now using Guzzle and OAuth2. Here is a request that I made but it throws an error:

```
    // This request works and it is just a simple route that returns a user.
        $client = new Client();
                $request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://example.dev/user');
                $response = $client->send($request);
                dd($response);

    // This one doesn't work, I don't know why. I have confirmed that the request
    // does send the post fields but the api responds with a 500. Although it does
    // work with POSTMAN. I have also tried sending it as Header but still doesn't work

        $client = new Client();
            $response = $client->post('http://example.dev/oauth/access_token', [
                'body' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => '1',
                    'client_secret' => '12345',
                    'username' => 'user@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'password123',
                ]
            ]);
            dd($response->json());
```

Comment: Are you using some specific packages to deal with JWT?

Comment: I also don't understand well your problem :) could you explain it better? :) thank you

Comment: yes i am using tymon/jwt-auth, and the route actually returns the token back properly, now we just need to save it in cookie and send it with every request.

Comment: Oh, ok, so you basically need to know how to work with cookies, right? Take a look to [this page on Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#cookies) to learn how to deal with cookies. All you have to do is to use your PHP app as any other app.

Comment: well actually i know how to work with cookies, but how do you send the token thats in the cookie with every post/get request?

Comment: Every time you send the token with JWT-Auth, you have two options: 1) you can send it as a query string parameter (in your $_GET array), or send it using headers. Like this: _Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}_.

Comment: Imho, you could create a middleware to add to the header data your cookie, if present. Right after that you could call to your API easily and work with them.

Comment: It seems that I'm not the only one: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/154

Comment: yes sending the token as authorization bearer is what i am after. can you please direct me to any turtorial that shows how to do that?

Comment: Well, actually it's not a best practice. If you are patience for 5 minutes I will explain you why in the answer! :)

Comment: Lol, sure i will wait for your response :)

Comment: Added my response. Go to the end of the answer to find what you need. Use the _merge_ method of the Request object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you should APIs externally. You have your business logic and then you expose an API to work with it. It's ok. However, if you're working in the same Laravel project it doesn't make any sense to "call the API" just like an external application would do: you're already inside your project context!

You should use something like *Guzzle* to make a call to your API just like an external service, but you would let your server do twice the work.

**What I Would Do**

If working "internally" in my project, I would **not** use APIs. They are interfaces, created for other external applications. Not for the application itself. :)

**What You Could Do**

So, even if I am not suggesting you to do this, but to think about your moves, here's a solution.

You could use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

More info:

- http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html;
- http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/psr7.html;

As you can see, you can freely set your headers and create a perfect request for your needs, but it doesn't make any sense.

Obviously you can't work internally with sessions, because you're using a token based auth system. So, use a middleware to inject your cookie in your "internal" request and then work with it as usual.

Here's an example of the middleware *handle* method body. You can merge an array of your choice with the existing request data with the *merge* method.

```
public function handle(Request $request)
{
    // getting the token
    $token = $request->cookie('token');

    // inject your token in the current request
    $request->merge(['token' => $token]);
}
```

Don't forget to add some validation data, to be sure that the token exists and you can use it.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: just for a complete answer... if you don't know how to create a middleware, [check this out](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware).

Comment: well actually this was just for testing purposes and in the real world i would have used something like lumen for the frontend ot keep it light. But i was not aware of gazzel and i think this would be perfect. Thankyou for this brilliant resource.

Comment: I just ran into some trouble. i have uploaded my code, the api should respond with an access token but it just resonds with a 500. But it works fine from post man. BTW I am using guzzle 5. Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Remember to double check what http verb you're using :)